GCP Cloud Functions Deployment Failing with ArtifactRegistry Error
Getting a really strange error when I try to deploy my cloud function in a particular project.  I run
gcloud config set project <project>
gcloud functions deploy my_cf --entry-point start_process \
--gen2 \
--trigger-http \
--region europe-west1 \
--runtime python310 \
--service-account <service account name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--no-allow-unauthenticated \
--source=./CloudFunction/

And my service account has what I would guess (based on the documentation) would be the necessary permissions and then some:
Artifact Registry Administrator
Cloud Functions Admin
Cloud Run Admin
Eventarc Event Receiver
Eventarc Service Agent
Pub/Sub Publisher
Service Account Token Creator
Storage Admin

However, I keep getting the error
OperationError: code=13, message=Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: An unexpected error occurred. Refer to build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=europe-west1/<build_id>?project=<project_number>

And when I check the Cloud Build Logs, I see error with message:
"Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to create image cache: accessing cache image 
"europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/<project>/gcf-artifacts/my--cf/cache:latest": 
connect to repo store "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/<project>/gcf-artifacts/<my--cf>/cache:latest": 
GET https://europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/token?scope=repository%3A<project>%2Fgcf-artifacts%2Fmy--cf%2Fcache%3Apull&service=: 
DENIED: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" 
denied on resource "projects/<project>/locations/europe-west1/repositories/gcf-artifacts" 
(or it may not exist)"

I have tried changing permission for both myself and the service account, but nothing seems to matter. Additionally, I have done this exercise in other projects and not had this issue.  Any ideas what is wrong?

I suspect (!) the issue is with the Cloud Build (!) Service Account not your (!?) Service Account. You can identify the Cloud Build Service Account with NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --format="value(projectNumber)") and then enumerate its roles using gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} --flatten="bindings[].members" --filter="bindings.members:${NUMBER}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" --format="value(bindings.role)" and then check whether the permission (!) artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts is included.

@DazWilkin the account did already have the role cloudbuild.builds.builder role which includes the above permission. I looked into the execution details of the build and it seems that its using the service account like ${NUMBER}-computer@developer.gserviceaccount.com. It was odd because it was using that even when I specified the service account my service uses and the cloud build service account to be the default for builds. Cloud Functions must have the default computer service account as a hard-overwrite.

Can you try adding the cloudfunctions.developer and iam.serviceAccountUser roles to the [PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` account. Also make sure that  cloudbuild service account also needs to be added as a member of the service account that has permissions to deploy your Cloud Function. Also have a look at this Documentation.

The fix is what I noted about. For some reason its the service account like ${NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com that is only doing the Cloud Build builds from Cloud Functions. I even tried changing the preferred to be the Legacy Cloud Build service account and the service account I use for my Cloud Function and that didn't work.

Seems the issue is that Cloud Functions seems to force Cloud Build to use ${NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com as the service account for its build jobs. The solution was to provide this service account with the artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts permission.
